# Removing and sorting elements from dynamically alocated structure

Tags: c

So i have few problems with my program for course credit. 
This program is supposed to be simply database witch keeps basic information about student like his name or his number. For now my program looks more or less like this:

(I wont paste here whole program, i think few parts of it will be enough to solve my problem)

Here is structure and variables:

```
typedef struct {
     char name[20];
     char surname[20];
     int student_id;
}data;


 data*student;
 int number_of_students=0;
 int menu_choice;
```

Here goes switch with menu options.

```
    switch(menu_choice)
    {
        case 1:

                system("cls");

                printf("Enter amount of students you want to put in data base\n");
                scanf("%d",&number_of_students);

                student=(data*)malloc(number_of_students*sizeof(data));
                adding_students_to_base( number_of_students);
        break;

        case 2:

                //deleting_records_from_base( number_of_students); 

        break;

        case 3:

                //print_base(number_of_students);

        break;

        case 4:

               // sorting_base( number_of_students);

        break;

        case 5:

                //saving_base_to_file( number_of_students);

        break;

        case 6:

                //loading_base_from_file();

        break;

        case 7:
                printf("Closing program!\n");
                _getch();
                exit(0);
        break;
     }
```

Adding and printing functions:

```
void adding_students_to_base(int amount_of_students)
{
  int i;


    system("cls");

   for ( i=0;i<amount_of_students;i++)
   {
       printf("\nName: ");
       scanf("%s",&(student+i)->name);
       printf("\nSurname: ");
       scanf("%s",&(student+i)->surname);
       printf("\nId number: ");
       scanf("%d",&(student+i)->student_id);
       system("cls");
   }

 system("cls");
}

void print_base(int amount_of_students)
{
   int i;

   system("cls");

   for ( i=0;i<amount_of_students;i++)
   {
       printf("\n----------|%d|-------------",i+1);
       printf("\nStudent_id: %d",(student+i)->student_id);
       printf("\nName: %s",(student+i)->name);
       printf("\nSurname: %s",(student+i)->surname);
       printf("\n---------------------------\n");

}

   _getch();
   system("cls");
}
```

I have managed to create working functions of adding, printing and saving data to base but i have no clue about how to deal with  problem sorting data.

Could you give me some hints, clues or code examples how to solve this problem?

EDIT

I managed to solve sorting problem. I wanted to add two last functions to my program, saving database and loading database  from txt file. 
I think that saving forks fine, it looks like this:

```
void saving_base_to_file(int amount_of_students)
{
    FILE *file;


    system("cls");
    printf("Saving base to file!\n");

    file=fopen("database.txt","wb");
    fprintf(file,"%d",amount_of_students);
    fwrite(student,sizeof( data),amount_of_students,file);  
    fclose(file);

    _getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

Problem appears when i want to use my "loading_base_from_file" function.
Function looks like this:

```
void loading_base_from_file()
{
    FILE *file;

    system("cls");
    printf("Reading base from file\n");

    file=fopen("database.txt","rb");

    if (file!= NULL) {
        fscanf(file,"%d",&number_of_students);
        fread(&student,sizeof( data),number_of_students,file); //number_of_students is global variable
        student=(data*)malloc(number_of_students*sizeof(data));
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File does not exist!.\r\n");
        printf("File have to be named ""database.txt"" !!!\n");
    }
    _getch();
    system("cls");
}
```

For example, when i want to save one student with student_id "123456" named "Greg" "Tesla", file contains this:
[database.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxuwr.png). Function saving_base_to_file also saves amount of students in base. But when i start my program again (or do  it in one program run) and try do load data from file, my function "print_base" prints this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0Nls.png)

I think that there is a problem with "putting" data into array, but i don't know what exactly is wrong.
Could you tell me why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What kind of sorting? You mean something like changing `id` by name or `id` by surname ?

Comment: An array is not the best structure for your purposes. To remove a student you need to find it in the array and then compact the array. It'll work but not that efficient as compaction is relatively costly. Better to use a linked list.

Comment: You should really show us what you've tried for the 'delete' functionality and explain what result you're getting and why it's wrong.  Similarly with the sorting — you should probably use [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html) and write an appropriate comparator function for two (pointers to) `student` records.

Comment: I want to sort them by student_id. It would be easier i think.

Comment: I edited the question. I think it is clearer and more understandable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, about your data structure: the number of students isn't fixed. You can remove students, so the size of your array `student` would change. Resizing an array is costly and laborious; you would benefit from using a linked list rather than an array.

If you really want to use an array:

- ask the user the ID of the student he wants to remove
- look for the index of that student in your array
- switch all students to the right of this index one place to the left (so the student your want to remove is overwritten and the last array cell is free)
- realloc your array 'cause you don't need that last array cell (use `realloc()`).

To sort your array, look into quick sort (often the most efficient — library function [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html)), insertion sort or selection sort (those are easier). You'll probably have to define a function to compare two students.

## edit

You asked for an example, I suppose that was with an array:

```
void delete(int *array, int index, int *size) {
    memmove(&(array[index]+1), &(array[index]), *size - index);
    (*size)--;
    realloc(array, size*sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: It is often reasonable to keep the array with two sizes: the number of records allocated and the number in use.  You can then avoid changing the allocation by one each time you add or remove a record — and if you add a record after removing one, you can avoid the overhead of a new memory allocation.  However, that may be more complex than the OP is ready to handle (though it really isn't very complex).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yup, I didn't want to make it too complex, linked list seemed the simplest way to achieve what OP wanted :) But you're absolutely right

Comment: I still got problem with deleting function. Could you show me how this supposed to look on simple example(just short fragment of code)?

Comment: @Eredin Edited my answer !

Comment: @WilliamDuclot, thank you for your support.But i have one last problem with my program, could you respond to my last edit?